# turning html source into strings in python

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse a website's source and then take chunks out of it.  The goal is to be able to concatenate this pieces and then send it through an e-mail to myself.

My issue is I cannot concatenate the items because they are in tag form.  How can I convert them to a string?

For instance, how could I convert the below into a python string object, or how could I programaticall wrap them arround the triple quotes (""")?  It would currently give me a syntax error.

```
<td align="left" class="table-2">Date</td>
<td align="left" class="table-2">Item</td>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a BeautifulSoup tag object, you can convert it to a string by calling `str`:

```
str(tag)
```

---

```
In [120]: import bs4 as bs

In [121]: soup = bs.BeautifulSoup('<td align="left" class="table-2">Date</td>')

In [122]: tag = soup.find('td')

In [123]: type(tag)
Out[123]: bs4.element.Tag

In [124]: str(tag)
Out[124]: '<td align="left" class="table-2">Date</td>'
```